# BottomSheetDialogFragment does the enter animation again on `onStart`. How to halt it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-animation, bottom-sheet

Everytime when the BottomSheetDialogFragment passes through the `onStart` lifecycle point, the enter window animation occurs again, as can be seen in the gif below.

[image]

What can be done to stop it from happening? I thought that it would only happen once, when the bottom action sheet was opened.

---

The code is as simple as that:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomSheet = CustomBottomSheetFragment()
        bottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, null)
    }
}
```

**CustomBottomSheetFragment.kt**

```
class CustomBottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = FrameLayout(requireContext())
        view.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            800
        )

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN)

        return view
    }

}
```

Obs.: "Don't keep activities" option is **not** enabled :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this Augusto?

Comment: This worked for me just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126613/how-can-i-stop-bottom-sheet-enter-animation-when-returning-to-screen-without-dis