# How can I stop Bottom sheet enter animation when returning to screen without disabling all animations

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment with the default enter and exit animation. When the lifecycle chages (eg. go to home screen and return to the app) the bottomsheet starting animations plays.

I have tried disabling animations with `setWindowAnimations(-1)`, however this also disables the exit animation when closing the dialog, which is not an option.

I show my bottomsheet this way:

```
MyBottomSheet.newInstance( ... ).show(parentFragmentManager, null)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do that in **onPause()** instead of **onStop()**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65287339/8011713).

```
override fun onPause() {
  super.onPause()
  dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1)
 }
```

To keep your animations when coming back, store the windowAnimation in a variable. You can retrieve the current animations with:         `dialog?.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations`

Then save it in **onSaveInstanceState** and once the App is resumed, just call **setWindowAnimations** again and set your saved animation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using in onStop():

```html
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that, but as I said, this also disables the exit animation when closing the bottom sheet, which is not an option for me in this case. 
Is there a way to re-enable animations (e.g. in onResume)?